# What's the difference between the snap store and the ubuntu software snap?

Tags: software-installation, snap, ubuntu-store

In ubuntu 20.04 the default store is a package called snap-store that is capable of installing both snaps and debs, but if you try to reinstall it with `snap remove snap-store` and `snap install snap-store` the package loses the ubuntu branding and the ability to install debs. How do I reinstall the original store and what difference is there with this snap store?

Answer (score 1):

Snaps have various channels available, by running `snap install snap-store` it defaults to the stable channel that isn't the one shipped by default in ubuntu 20.04 store. Running `snap switch snap-store --channel edge` after installation will switch the snap to the edge channel and give back the ability to install debs and the ubuntu branding.

So to answer the question, they are different channels of the same package, which can be confusing because of how different they are.